# Python Inner Class Inheritence

Tags: python-3.x, inheritance, inner-classes

I'm trying to define my `config.py` using `class` in Python, such that, every class will have some "static" members, that will be read for my configuration settings. I'm using inner classes and using inheritence among them.

Here is an example of what I'm trying to do:

```
class Prod:
    class default_configs:
        var1 = "pppp"
        var2 = var1 + "D"

    class mode1(default_configs):
        var2 = default_configs.var1 + "M1"

    class mode2(default_configs):
        var2 = "M2"

 ...
 ...

class Local:
    pass
```

I'm getting the error when I'm setting `var2` in `class mode1`. It says:

> "default_configs is not defined"

as if, it is treating `default_configs` as a member-variable. So, what am I doing wrong and how can I get this to work? Also, `mode2.var1` and `mode2.var2` have values as expected.

I tried using parent reference as well, like `Prod.default_configs.var1` but that did not work either. I also tried accessing `var1` directly, as if inherited, it should be usable, but I was wrong again.

Answer (score 1):

I think you're overworking your solution a bit. Inheritance and static variables and methods can be handled quite easily in Python.

Given your example above, let's say we have a `Config` class, which has a couple of static attributes and methods, and you want to create both `Local` and `Prod` classses which both inherit from a base class `Config`:

```py
class Config:
    var1 = "pppp"  # These two are class variables now
    var2 = var1 + "D"

    def __init__(self):
        self.var3 = 'Local variable'
        self.var4 = None  # We define it here so it doesn't throw an exception afterwards

    @staticfunction
    def mode1(cls):
        """
        Here we use the cls variable to reference the class, as we would
        do with self in an instance method
        """
        cls.var2 = cls.var1 + "M1"

    def instance_function(self):
        self.val4 = 'Instance variable'


class Prod(Config):

    def mode2(self):
        print(self.var2)  # ppppD
        super().var2 = "M2"  # The parent class in subclasses is defined by super()
        self.var2 = "M3"  # super().var2 and self.var2 will have different values
        print(super().var2)  # M2
        super().model()
        print(super().var2)  # M1

        print(super().var3)  # Throws Exception: Variable not found
        print(self.var3)  # Local variable

        print(self.var4)  # None
        self.instance_method()
        print(self.var4)  # Instance variable


class Local(Config):

    def __init__(self):
        """
        This runs the superclass constructor. It's run by default on single-class
        inheritance, but let's run it anyway just for the sake of it.
        """
        super().__init()__

    def mode2(self):
        print(super().var2)  # ppppD
        super().var2 = "M2"  # The parent class in subclasses is defined by super()
        print(super().var2)  # M2
        print(self.var2)  # M3
```

Comment: I finally used this approach to set thie config. It just feels easier this way. Although it does not answer my exact question, this approach solves my overall issue. So, thanks :)